# Recommended Role to Create and Manage users and roles in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Which of the following roles is recommended to be used to create and manage users and roles?
A. SYSADMIN
B. SECURITYADMIN
C. PUBLIC
D. ACCOUNTADMIN

I am doubtful with SecurityAdmin or AccountAdmin because both will be able to perform the creation and managing of roles and users but in terms of recommendation can anyone suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good schematic to explain the role hierachy in Snowflake, especially with respect to the out-of-the-box roles:
[image]

ACCOUNTADMIN is the "top level", ie most powerful, role in Snowflake. It encapsulates the SYSADMIN and SECURITYADMIN system-defined roles and  should be used sparingly.

SECURITYADMIN can manage any object grant globally, as well as create, monitor, and manage users and roles. More specifically, this role is granted the `MANAGE GRANTS` security privilege to be able to modify any grant, including revoking it, and inherits the privileges of the USERADMIN role via the system role hierarchy (e.g. USERADMIN role is granted to SECURITYADMIN).

USERADMIN is dedicated to user and role management only. More specifically, this role is granted the `CREATE USER` and `CREATE ROLE` security privileges, and can create users and roles in the account. This role can also manage users and roles that it owns. Only the role with the `OWNERSHIP` privilege on an object (i.e. user or role), or a higher role, can modify the object properties. In addition, the role must have the global `CREATE USER` or `CREATE ROLE` privilege, respectively, to modify users or roles it owns.

SYSADMIN has privileges to create virtual warehouses and databases (and other objects) in an account. If, as recommended, you create a role hierarchy that ultimately assigns all custom roles to the SYSADMIN role, this role also has the ability to grant privileges on warehouses, databases, and other objects to other roles.

PUBLIC is pseudo-role that is automatically granted to every user and every role in your account. The PUBLIC role can own securable objects, just like any other role; however, the objects owned by the role are, by definition, available to every other user and role in your account.This role is typically used in cases where explicit access control is not needed and all users are viewed as equal with regard to their access rights.

So, the correct answer is USERADMIN but since USERADMIN is not an option, we should choose the lowest-level role which has the necdessary privileges to manage users and roles, which, as we see from the diagram and the explanation above, should be SECURITYADMIN.

Comment: Hi Robert.. Thank you for the explanation. As suggested, as UserAdmin is not an option so will consider SecurityAdmin for this question...

Answer (score 1):

Answer your question, none of the given. **USERADMIN** is recommended for this task.

The SECURITYADMIN role has too high permission, it can even grant ACCOUNTADMIN permission to itself or someone else.
References: [Overview of Access Control](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-overview.html)

It is worth adding that there is another very important top role: ORGADMIN, more about it here: [Enabling the ORGADMIN Role](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/organizations-gs.html).

Comment: Thank you Michael for the suggestion. I have never heard about OrgAdmin will deep dive into it now.